# Xtext: define 2 DSL's in one project

Tags: eclipse, xtext

How do you define two DSL's in one Eclipse project?

The first DSL is used as input syntax where the user specify a design. The design needs to be converted into a different language. The different language is defined by the second DSL. For the transformation I intend to use Epsilon Transformation Language (ETL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

having two dsl in one project is not neccessary for your usecase. if you want to do it anyway you can add multiple language sections to the workflow like

```
    language = StandardLanguage {
        name = "org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl"
        fileExtensions = "mydsl"

        serializer = {
            generateStub = false
        }
        validator = {
            // composedCheck = "org.eclipse.xtext.validation.NamesAreUniqueValidator"
        }
    }

    language = StandardLanguage {
        name = "org.xtext.example.otherdsl.OtherDsl"
        fileExtensions = "mydsl2"

        serializer = {
            generateStub = false
        }
        validator = {
            // composedCheck = "org.eclipse.xtext.validation.NamesAreUniqueValidator"
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the advantage to define each DSL in a separate project?

Comment: It's clear if the dsl do not have a strong relationship and you have the possibility to deploy them independently